# Whats the best way to display message after CRUD operation In Django

Tags: django, django-templates

I have been doing CRUD operation in Django but I am having problem with what to do after successful operation.

Is there any way that i can redirect the user to Home page with small message on top of page like

`"Record Successfully added or something else"` like Google does with Dismiss hyperlink :)

EDIT:

Actually that a is full documentation and not a simple example.

1. I could not understand in which template I have to include `{{messages}}` in. In update form, edit form or home page form?
2. I don't understand where I need to define messages. I use only generic views so I am confused.

Comment: Did you read this?  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/messages/

Comment: I read that but could fully unserstood , there is too muc detail there. Any simple example??

Comment: The examples are in there.  They are complete and they work.  What more do you need?  Please **update** the question to list specific things on that page which you did not understand.  Please ask **specific** questions about the message framework.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [django.contrib.messages](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/messages/) framework to get the same messaging style as used in Django admin.

1. Enable the middleware module by adding `'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware'` to `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` in settings.py.
2. In your view, use something like `messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'Stuff happened')` to record information where it makes sense.
3. In your template, you'll have a list `messages` which you can iterate over where it makes sense in your design - [the example in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/messages/#displaying-messages) shows a full example which exposes the tags as CSS classes for ease of styling.